# Where are the folder view and file sorting/grouping settings stored in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, window, sorting

I can observe that Windows 10 remembers folder settings such as "Sort by" and "Group by" for each folder. Where are those settings and customizations stored?

Comment: Somewhere in the registry, most likely somewhere below Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Local views are stored under:

`HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

Desktop layout & network folders under:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

The views are indexed via the adjacent **BagMRU** key.

Don't re-invent the wheel. what is it you want to do?

Comment: Full registry settings here>>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1550680/40928