# Where does win7 store folder columns settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Windows file explorer columns show/hide (size, date, type, etc..). Where does Windows 7 store these settings? Are they stored for each individual folder?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most settings are kept in the registry. The complete list of these keys is:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

You might find useful this article and its `.bat` file:
[How to Backup and Restore Folder View Settings in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17777-backup-restore-folder-view-settings-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is Win 10. I skipped 7 but think paths are similar.
The default views for the various *FolderTypes* are found in the subkeys of:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
```

There are GUID-named *FolderTypes* (Generic, Documemts, Music, etc.) defined here, each has a subkey named *TopViews* with one or more GUID-named subkeys that specify default view settings. In these keys, the column information is in a relatively human-readable form. The value is named **ColumnList**:

```
gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'


ColumnList      : prop:0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.DateModified;0System.ItemTypeText;0System.
                  Size;1System.DateCreated;1System.Author;1System.Keywords;1System.Title
LogicalViewMode : 1
Name            : NoName
Order           : 0
PSPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\C
                  urrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\
                  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
PSParentPath    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\C
                  urrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews
PSChildName     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
PSDrive         : HKLM
PSProvider      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

The "0" prefix means the column displays by default. The "1" prefix places the column in the top section of the context menu displayed when you right-click on column headers. Width is optional and is seen above as the "**(34)**" in **0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay**. 34 -> 340 pixels.

Folders that have been viewed in **Explorer** or via a common dialog save their individual views under the **Bags** subkeys.
[image]

Here, the column information is in binary format in the **ColInfo** value. I just recently finally took the time to parse/decode this value and explain it in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data/61240563#61240563).

**HKCU...\Explorer\Streams\Defaults** stores the custom templates created by **Apply to Folders**. These are binary structures containing the same settings found under **Bags**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers!

@Keith I've also looked at your other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data/61240563#61240563, helped a lot.

Is it possible to get registry key of the current folder with a batch script?

Comment: correction: registry key Slot Number

Comment: You mean the Bag# ? Yes, but given the nature of **BagMRU**, you need the complete namespace path to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Could you post a link to more info as to how to do that?

p.s. I've exported the registry entry for folder 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\956\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}

changed 956 to 812, ran the reg file and the folder with 812 slot number changed to the same view as 956. So basically all I need to have are preset *.reg files and bat script that gets the slot number of current folder.